# Angularjs ng-click not firing in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have `<li>`list in ng-repeat and this list is updated every second. In list I have few fields and action buttons with ng-click directive. So every second when data is updated in list `<li>` list is rendered again and in this moment ng-click is not firing, probably because in this small specific moment click is not bound to button.

Here is the small sample of code.

```
<ul class="items-list">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: ['id', 'date']">
        <div>{{ item.id }}</div>
        <div>{{ item.size }}</div>
        <div>{{ item.date }}</div>
        <div ng-click="deleteEntry($event)"><img src="delete.png"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.deleteEntry = function(event) {
    console.log("delete"); // sometimes this does not log
}

$interval(function() {
    $scope.items = someService.getItems();
}, 1000, 0, true);
```

Data is changing correctly but in this render time click is not firing.

Comment: Weird scenario. How is this button supposed to be clicked by a user if the list keeps updating every second. Does it ever stop?

Comment: It does not stop updating and button is visible and clickable all the time.

Comment: If you think that the $interval is messing with the click. Why don't you just remove the interval and you will know the answer to that question...

Comment: But I have to refresh data every second.

Answer (score 0):

you want pass an object to the function `<div ng-click="deleteEntry(item)"><img src="delete.png"></div>` so you can perform any operation on each `<li>` tag in `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 0):

Make the below code run.

```
$interval(function() {
  var getAllItems = someService.getItems();
  getAllItems.map(function(item){
      //check for the item that not present in $scope.items and push that item to $scope.items
      $scope.items.push(item);
  }); 
}, 1000, 0, true);
```

Also,

```
ng-click="deleteEntry(item)"
```

Comment: interval callback can be empty. with third param 'true' $digest will be called and in this moment click will fail. In case param is 'false'
click will work as expected but html will not be update because missing of $digest.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Event Delegation** using jquery to make delete call on each element.

Refer:https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2448-using-jquery-event-delegation-in-angularjs.htm

Hope this help,what you looking for.